# Unable to see the containers in Docker Toolsbox

Tags: docker

I have installed docker toolsbox in windows 10.
I have created a container for mysql for the an application using the docker command as given. I'm able to create it and also able to view it using the docker container ls command, but only for the first time.

The Problem occurs when closing the docker toolsbox and reopen it.
When I issued the **docker container ls** command, I'm unable to find any of the containers what I have created.

But When I tried to inspect the container I'm able to view the container details.

Attached the screenshot and json details of the container.

Please let me know in case of more information needed.

**Docker command for creating the MySQL container**

```
docker run --name mysql-docker-petclinic -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -e MYSQL_DATABASE=petclinic -e MYSQL_USERNAME=root -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:latest
```

**Inspect Command Details**

```
$ docker container inspect mysql-docker-petclinic
[
    {
        "Id": "f30f66154b7398bbfd1b65d34afc0d973ecdbe62d0e2cbd654003775d11499e0",
        "Created": "2018-02-25T16:28:10.327158448Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "mysqld"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 255,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-02-25T16:28:12.428822667Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2018-02-26T04:38:54.98958199Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:f0f3956a9dd825e3195f0d1a4fe17cc94b0f6934fc470b09abf8fad87d17ff24",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/f30f66154b7398bbfd1b65d34afc0d973ecdbe62d0e2cbd654003775d11499e0/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/f30f66154b7398bbfd1b65d34afc0d973ecdbe62d0e2cbd654003775d11499e0/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/f30f66154b7398bbfd1b65d34afc0d973ecdbe62d0e2cbd654003775d11499e0/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/f30f66154b7398bbfd1b65d34afc0d973ecdbe62d0e2cbd654003775d11499e0/f30f66154b7398bbfd1b65d34afc0d973ecdbe62d0e2cbd654003775d11499e0-json.log",
        "Name": "/mysql-docker-petclinic",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "3306/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "3306"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                30,
                120
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "7195ae34c4698fbcdf3737962e799e991e0268a33ea6126af8b0e4aa24b2b18e",
                "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/7195ae34c4698fbcdf3737962e799e991e0268a33ea6126af8b0e4aa24b2b18e/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "f30f66154b73",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin",
                "MYSQL_DATABASE=petclinic",
                "MYSQL_USERNAME=root",
                "MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7",
                "MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.21-1debian8"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mysqld"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "mysql:latest",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "0f9a23a942344c2e7c23d425456787db327278dec4601447eb526dfdaa9c3abb",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "3306"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/0f9a23a94234",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "*********************************************************",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "*********************************",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "*********************************************************",
                    "EndpointID": "*********************************************************",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "*********************************************************",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**Screenshots**

***1. Docker ls command***

[image]

**2. Docker Inspect Command Details**

[image]

**------------- UPDATE -------------**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`docker container ls`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_ls/#usage) by default shows only the *running* container.

> closing the docker toolsbox and reopen it

That means all your containers are now in "Exited" state.

Try:

```
docker container ls --all
```

See also `docker ps -a`

Comment: update screenshot available as said I'm able to view only with help docker ps -a command. Additionally I have another problem I have a spring boot app in my local but I couldn't connet with the mysql available in the container. What causing these issues ??? Is it working correctly ????

Comment: what is use just able to see it? I have raised another query for execution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084181/unable-to-execute-spring-boot-in-docker-toolsbox